# Do not re-evaluate condition in conditional assignment

Tags: python

Is there a way to do the following in a one-liner:

```py
x = heavy_computation() if heavy_computation() > 0 else None
```

without `heavy_computation()` being called twice? Of course, one could do:

```py
val = heavy_computation()
x = val if val > 0 else None
```

but I was wondering if there is a more pythonic way to achieve this in one line. This might be useful for heavy computations but also for better code readability.

Comment: it depends. If negative values aren't possible, for example, `heavy_computation() or None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using the walrus operator ([PEP 572](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/)):

```py
x = val if (val := heavy_computation()) > 0 else None
```

Note that it requires a recent Python version (at least 3.8).

I'm not sure if it's much more readable though.

Comment: Thanks! I think it's less readable than the common if else but still better than using two lines